# Unable to search datatable with fixed column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables to display a table using ajax. When I fix the first column it cannot be search/filtered? my code as follows:

```
      var quotetable = $('#quotelog-table').DataTable(
    {
    "ajax": {"url": "functions/ajax-getquotelog.php", "type": "POST"},
            "deferRender": true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            fixedColumns: {
            leftColumns: 1
            },
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: "560px",
            colReorder: true,
            select: {
            style: 'single'
            },
            "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Showing _MENU_ records per page",
                    "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
                    "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_ of _MAX_ items",
                    "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
            },
            "lengthMenu": [[20, 25, 50, 100, - 1], [20, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]

        }); // end of datatable.

 // Apply the search
    quotetable.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {

        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
```

The page renders correctly - I can view all and sort in all fields except the first one (that is fixed?) If I remove the fixedColumns from the code it works correctly. Is this a bug or does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried to define the column as searchable like that : "columns": [
    { "searchable": true },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    ...
  ] ? (I know it's true by default, but you can still try....)

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.

It appears the fixedColumns entry in the datatable:

```
fixedColumns: {
                leftColumns: 1
                },
```

is generating a duplicate text input box for that column. ( class .DTFC_LeftFootWrapper)  The other input boxes are rendered beforehand.

by adding the following to my css the unwanted text boxes are not displayed.

```
.DTFC_LeftFootWrapper {
    display:none;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Tony

Answer (score 1):

```
<Script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var dt = $('#sample').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "serverRequest/manage_login.php",
        "columns": [
        null,null,null,
{ "searchable": false },null,{ "searchable": false },{ "searchable": false },null,{ "searchable": false },{ "searchable": false }
        ]

    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is regarding Bootstrap Datatables, there's an example in the documentation [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/styling/col_filter.html).